# How would I create this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

I understand this isn't possibly the best title so please edit if you have a better title.

Ok, so I have a mock up of part of the design I want to create in android, which I will post below.

I am not the best in working with custom shapes so I thought I could possibly go down the route of [Images with clickable areas](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/). This would mean I just import the image and just monitor if the user clicks a section of the screen.

What would be the best approach?

If creating it with XML is better do you have a good tutorial you could point me to.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Create a RelativeLayout as main layout. Next Add LinearLayout (vertical) which will contain two horizontal Layout. and add Imageview(set as alignCenterinparent=true of circle type before closing relative

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, I will give it ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This May Help**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 3"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/></RelativeLayout>
```

> Keep this file in drawable folder for circle button background named as circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

<size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" /></shape>
```

**Looks Like This**

[image: Your Layout]

Comment: Looks great. thanks. For some reason the circle is not rendering in the designer but I will have to find out whats wrong.(I have the shape named circle) But this is great thanks, I will mark this as answer :)  (Has now rendered....the new android studio is a little buggy)

Comment: your are having problem with circle? Just create drawable folder in res and inside keep one xml file for circular background let say circle.xml and keep this code in it. code : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

<size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" /></shape>

Comment: add this file as background to center button as shown in layout file

Comment: Yea its ok android studio wasn't rendering it but its ok now thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully tested layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button one"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_1"
        android:text="Button two"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button three"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_3"
        android:text="Button four"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ti_logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ SammyG you can edit in this layout according to your requirements..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.stackoverflow_test.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:padding="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            android:padding="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /></RelativeLayout>
```